# Finding user ip and see if matches range of ips

Tags: php

i am trying to find users who come from a specific company (using i.p Address) and capture their personal data through a webform.

Before i wanted to find a user i.p address and see if it appeared in a single range of i.p's but i want to have multiple ip ranges defined and only match to those specified:

-find user ip
-see if it matches any of the ip ranges set
-if so show form else do nothing

I have the below code i was working on as an example:

```
<?php

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$private_ip_ranges = array();

$range = (object) array();
$range->name = 'Media';
$range->lower = '212.1.0.0';
$range->upper = '212.1.255.255';
$private_ip_ranges[] = $range

$range = (object) array();
$range->name = 'Media 2';
$range->lower = '213.1.0.0';
$range->upper = '213.1.255.255';
$private_ip_ranges[] = $range

foreach ($private_ip_ranges as $ip_range) {
    if (in_ip_range($ip, $range->lower, $range->upper)) {
        echo "webform";
    }
}





?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ip2long function before comparison

```
if (($lngIP=ip2long($ip)) < 0) $lngIP += 4294967296;  

foreach ($private_ip_ranges as $ip_range) {
   if (($lngLow=ip2long($ip_range->lower)) < 0) $lngLow += 4294967296;
   if (($lngHigh=ip2long($ip_range->upper)) < 0) $lngHigh += 4294967296;
   if($lngIP >= $lngLow and $lngIP <= $lngHigh) {
        echo "webform";
    }
}
```